# Visual studio suggestion window covers code

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, visualgdb

I am developing in C/C++ using Visual Studio Community and Visual GDB. When I type things, the intellisense suggestion window covers the code so that I cant see anything. And as I type the windows does not move to the right along with the characters that I have written so far.

Please see the pic I have attached.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there is no way to resize suggestion window so far. But when you type the windows will change its height automatically along with the characters that you have written. Then you will see the code covered by suggestion window.

Test environment visual studio 2022(17.7.4) community

[image]

You could submit a feature request via
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your comment. I have updated my original post to include a short video to show how your and my result are not the same. I should not that VS is open on a second monitor. If I have VS open on my laptop primary monitor, then it presents itself like on your end. But on my second monitor, it does undesirable things.

Comment: Hi Misha, from looking at  your video, it seems like an issue with intellisense window. it's recommended to report this issue and create a new ticket from [developercommunity](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report) to identify the issue.